# Calculating total lines added/deleted after a merge?

Tags: git, merge

I recently took a branch with a lot of commits and merged it back into my master branch. If I needed to go back and see how many lines were added or deleted because of that merge, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`git diff` has a `--shortstat` option which would have been useful before the merge as then you could've just done `git diff --shortstat ..branch/to/merge` from your main branch.

If the merge wasn't a fast-forward, then you'll have generated a merge commit.  That will have the parent information for both branches.  You can use those to do `git diff --shortstat parent1..mergecommit` to show what changes happened when moving from the first parent (your main branch) to the result of the merge commit.

If the merge was a fast-forward, then you just need to know what the sha1 of your branch was before the merge and compare that to the current.  You could probably get that from `git reflog`.

Answer (score 14):

```
git diff --shortstat commit1 commit2
```

should give you what you want:

```
git diff --shortstat 8fcb60bebc18b9ee4a5a0a86d41e8ecf954b8c99 0214060c21f31f9b54446dde6b6e48901e6a144d
5 files changed, 182 insertions(+), 225 deletions(-)
```

See [git tricks](http://grml.org/git/git_tricks.pdf)  for more information:

```
--shortstat
```

> Output only the last line of the `--stat` format containing total number of modified files, as well as number of added and deleted lines.

---

Note:
You can even use it to compute some [daily activity](http://jbowes.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/graphing-git-repository-activity-in-ascii/)

[image: https://jbowes.files.wordpress.com/2008/05/screenshot-git-graphpl.png?w=490&h=342]

Answer (score 3):

`^` (carat) gets you parent rev, so you could:

`git diff --shortstat abc123^ abc123`

Answer (score 1):

Use a diff utility to compare the main branch version of the file before and after the merge.

WinMerge (if you're using Windows) would be a good one to use.